# To add hyperlink in grid

Tags: c#, gridview, hyperlink

Iam building a web application. which requires a grid view with drill down . 
Code

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net.Mail;

public partial class PcocDash : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string id = string.Empty;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtprocdash = new DataTable();

    dtprocdash.Columns.Add("UOM");
    dtprocdash.Columns.Add("Jan");
    dtprocdash.Columns.Add("Feb");
    dtprocdash.Columns.Add("Mar");
```

#region PRStatus Header
       DataRow dr = dtprocdash.NewRow();
        dr["UOM"] = "";

```
    dtprocdash.Rows.Add(dr);
```

## endregion

## region No of POs

```
    DataRow drprwithsla = dtprocdash.NewRow();
     drprwithsla["UOM"] = "No";                    
            SqlConnection co1 = new SqlConnection();

    co1.ConnectionString = DataBaseOperation.GetConnectioString();
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
    cmd1.Connection = co1;
    cmd1.CommandText = strQuery;
    co1.Open();
    //SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    SqlDataReader rd1;
    rd1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
    while (rd1.Read())
    {
        drprwithsla[2] = rd1["Jan"].ToString();
        drprwithsla[3] = rd1["Feb"].ToString();

        drprwithsla[4] = rd1["Mar"].ToString();


    }
    co1.Close();
```

dtprocdash.Rows.Add(drprwithsla);

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
            {
                GridViewRow gvRow = e.Row;
                gvRow.Cells[0].Text = "PR Status";
                gvRow.Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                gvRow.Cells[0].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                gvRow.Cells[0].Font.Italic = true;
                gvRow.Cells[0].Font.Bold = true;

```
        }
        if (e.Row.RowIndex == 1)
        {
            GridViewRow gvRow = e.Row;
            gvRow.Cells[0].Text = "Total no of PR's";
            gvRow.Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Wheat;
            gvRow.Cells[0].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
            gvRow.Cells[0].Font.Italic = true;
        }
```

}

The issue is i have  created a grid in aspx page and all the columns have been added in .cs file . Please some one help me out . how to add hyperlink in this page . Iam really new to the .net . Thanks in advance for any response

Answer (score 1):

Add a Hyperlink field

read more here :http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/webforms/controls/addinghyperlinkfieldstogridview.aspx

and here: [How do I programmatically fill a gridview's bound (hyperlink) column dynamically and then use the column's value as the url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686891/how-do-i-programmatically-fill-a-gridviews-bound-hyperlink-column-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code to add a hyperlink in grid view.

**Windows Application:**

```
DataGridViewLinkColumn View = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
View.HeaderText = "";
View.Width = 30;
View.Name = "View";
View.Text = "Print";
gv_CRWS_details.Columns.Insert(0, View);
```

**WebApplication:**

```
GridViewLinkColumn View = new GridViewLinkColumn();
    View.HeaderText = "";
    View.Width = 30;
    View.Name = "View";
    View.Text = "Print";
    gv_CRWS_details.Columns.Insert(0, View);
```